# Hi, I'm new to Ubuntu & can't get my DVDRW to work at all, please help

Tags: 14.04, dvd

I am running 14.04 64bit.
New to Ubuntu & learning as fast as I can.

I had a dvdrom in the system but it wasn't working (turns out I had a bad cable)
I switched it out with a working DVDRW from another system I wasn't using any more.
The tray opens and closes
The status led blinks green when I insert a disc (CDDA, DVD, DATA)
I hear the drive spool up but it doesn't do any more than that.

I can run some commands in terminal but need assistance with the required command lines.

Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a strong possibility that a wrong-state error is present. You may have cleared the drive via the hardware while the computer was doing a shutdown. This creates a wrong-state error.

If a disk is removed from a optical drive, while the system is shutting down, I have found that the driver can become confused, and upon restart, the system still thinks there is a disk in the drive, when in fact it is empty. You will see the drive icon in the Launcher, even though the drive is empty. System cannot read a empty drive that is thought to be occupied.

Just right-click upon the drive icon, and eject the drive. Then close the drive and insure that the icon is flushed from the Launcher. Then Restart the system. Then install a disk and see if it reads. This has fixed many problems for me.

The above is a clear defect in the command routing software in the hardware layer. All other OS's check the contents of the drive at boot time and flush the active mode if nothing is in the drive, regardless of the last state record. Ubuntu has not fixed this error and it has been present forever. I always make sure the drive is empty before I shutdown the computer, to preclude this error.

Hope that helps, have fun and good luck!

Comment: The drive is cleared, it only shows in launcher when I insert a disc.